# coloring by a group using ggscatter in R

Tags: r, grouping, ggpubr

I am using ggscatter function from ggpubr library to make a scatter plot.
My data frame looks like this

```
1   a   b   chr17   +   0.003   0.005   0,2 282232  4,0 253259  non_sig
10  a   b   chr22   -   0.733   0.6855  16,17   3,3 24,45   11,4    non_sig
12  a   b   chr13   +   0.7625  0.7965  22,14   1,7 7,18    1,4 non_sig
14  a   b   chr13   +   0.4555  0.369   20,16   19,12   4,23    17,11   non_sig
15  a   b   chr13   +   0.488   0.384   27,15   19,12   7,18    17,11   non_sig
16  a   b   chr16   -   0.9715  0.978   200141  3,2 260280  3,3 non_sig
21  a   b   chr1    +   0.9365  0.933   149118  1,12    133175  11,5    non_sig
22  a   b   chrX    +   0.6475  0.7265  129,57  58,35   104,78  37,29   non_sig
26  a   b   chr3    +   0.05    0.0475  54,32   721503  46,27   519617  non_sig
27  a   b   chr3    +   0.0475  0.045   57,34   721503  47,30   519617  non_sig
```

This is the command I am using

```
library("ggpubr")
df <- read.table("test.txt",header =F,sep="\t")
ggscatter(df,x= "V6",y= "V7",color = "V12", shape = 21, size = 1,add = "reg.line",cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",conf.int = TRUE,title="A3SS(4561)",xlab="Ψ2",ylab = "Ψ1",
                  palette = c("black", "red"))
```

I want to color the points using 12th column which has either **`non_sig`** or **`sig`** as the value and on base of that, if `non_sig`, I want it to be `black` and if `sig`, I want it to be `red`

When I use the above code it does what I want, but how can I specifically code here for

```
sig=>red
non_sig=>black
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: In a sense, you are already coding the colours. The variables in column 12 will be ordered alphabetically: first `non_sig`, then `sig`. Your palette is assigned in order, so "black" goes to the first factor (`non_sig`) and "red" to the second (`sig`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand now that it works here, but let's suppose there are three variable in column12 and I want to assign colors to them in a way I know and not based on alphabetical order, how can I do that?

Comment: Added an answer which hopefully helps.

Answer (score 7):

I assume by *"color the points using 12the column"* you mean to *fill* points with a colour based on column `V12`.

Note that your sample data only contains `V12 = "non_sig"` entries, so I have manually changed one entry to `"sig"`

```
library(ggpubr)
ggscatter(
    df,
    x= "V6", y= "V7",
    fill = "V12",
    shape = 21,
    size = 5,
    add = "reg.line",
    cor.coef = TRUE,
    cor.method = "pearson",
    conf.int = TRUE,
    title="A3SS(4561)",
    xlab="Ψ2",
    ylab = "Ψ1",
    palette = c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "1   a   b   chr17   +   0.003   0.005   0,2 282232  4,0 253259  non_sig
10  a   b   chr22   -   0.733   0.6855  16,17   3,3 24,45   11,4    non_sig
12  a   b   chr13   +   0.7625  0.7965  22,14   1,7 7,18    1,4 non_sig
14  a   b   chr13   +   0.4555  0.369   20,16   19,12   4,23    17,11   non_sig
15  a   b   chr13   +   0.488   0.384   27,15   19,12   7,18    17,11   sig
16  a   b   chr16   -   0.9715  0.978   200141  3,2 260280  3,3 non_sig
21  a   b   chr1    +   0.9365  0.933   149118  1,12    133175  11,5    non_sig
22  a   b   chrX    +   0.6475  0.7265  129,57  58,35   104,78  37,29   non_sig
26  a   b   chr3    +   0.05    0.0475  54,32   721503  46,27   519617  non_sig
27  a   b   chr3    +   0.0475  0.045   57,34   721503  47,30   519617  non_sig", header = F)
```

---

### Update

In response to your comment, you can use a *named* vector for your `palette` argument; e.g.

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "1   a   b   chr17   +   0.003   0.005   0,2 282232  4,0 253259  non_sig
10  a   b   chr22   -   0.733   0.6855  16,17   3,3 24,45   11,4    non_sig
12  a   b   chr13   +   0.7625  0.7965  22,14   1,7 7,18    1,4 non_sig
14  a   b   chr13   +   0.4555  0.369   20,16   19,12   4,23    17,11   non_sig
15  a   b   chr13   +   0.488   0.384   27,15   19,12   7,18    17,11   sig
16  a   b   chr16   -   0.9715  0.978   200141  3,2 260280  3,3 non_sig
21  a   b   chr1    +   0.9365  0.933   149118  1,12    133175  11,5    non_sig
22  a   b   chrX    +   0.6475  0.7265  129,57  58,35   104,78  37,29   test
26  a   b   chr3    +   0.05    0.0475  54,32   721503  46,27   519617  non_sig
27  a   b   chr3    +   0.0475  0.045   57,34   721503  47,30   519617  non_sig", header = F)


ggscatter(
    df,
    x= "V6", y= "V7",
    fill = "V12",
    shape = 21,
    size = 5,
    palette = c(test = "black", sig = "red", non_sig = "orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize, I don't have a sig value here. I see you used fill instead of color argument, but in this case it is alphabetically assigned, what if I have a third variable test and I want it to be black and sig to red and non_sig to be orange. How will I do that?

Comment: @user3138373 You can use a named vector for `palette`; I've updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know I can use names within <palette>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the variables in column 12 are factors, their default ordering is alphabetical. So in your example the first palette colour ("black") goes to the first factor level ("non_sig"); the second colour ("red") goes to the second factor ("sig").

If you want to assign colours differently, you need to reorder either the factor levels or the colour names in the palette. For example to assign "black", "red" and "green" to the factors "sig", "non_sig" and "new_var", you could do something like:

```
df$V12 <- factor(df$V12, levels = c("sig", "non_sig", "new_var"))
```

then in the plot:

```
palette = c("black", "red", "green")
```